# Error saving DocuSign Envelope Status in Salesforce using Apex Toolkit

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Since September 30th, we started receiving errors while trying to create DocuSign Status records:

> All envelopes must be in 'sent' or 'created' state with a valid DocuSign ID to create associated status records

We are using the [EnvelopeService Apex Toolkit](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/envelopeservice.html), and the exception is thrown after invoking the *saveSentEnvelopes* or *sendEnvelope* methods.
Sometimes it fails and sometimes it works, so we could not determine any pattern in terms of the envelope we are sending.
Moreover, the users are receiving the email with the envelope correctly.

Comment: Random even in same sandbox? If it's making callouts or logging back in to org my money would be on enhanced domain critical update or maybe package version they updated in 1 sandbox but not another... You may have to simply contact support

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, even in Sandbox it has odd behavior. We updated to the latest version of the package, but it wasn't the solution. We contacted support but maybe having this question here could help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue for which a patch was released yesterday. Please update your DocuSign Apps Launcher to the [latest version](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t3u000002zolr) to resolve this

Comment: Thanks Karan! That solved the issue at least in Sandbox.